Java recipes are not working for component-test package
I have below project structure:-
my-project/
├── pom.xml
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   ├── resources/
│   ├── test/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   ├── resources/
│   ├── component-test/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   ├── resources/
└── ... (other project files and directories)

Where we have a component-test folder also with java classes inside and we have separate maven commands to run component test.
If I write a recipe to change in Java classes like org.openrewrite.java.ChangeType then it works for all folders except component-test. Actually I can`t modify my-project pom.xml to run component test along with recipe command because I have to run same recipe for multiple projects. But I can do any modifications in my-recipe project.
Do we have any solution so that component-test folder also get considered while running open-rewrite recipe? below command I am executing to run my recipe:-
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:dryRun -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=com.hello.myproject:myproject-migration:5.0.30 -Drewrite.activeRecipes=com.hello.myproject.my-recipe-migrate-5

Note: Text recipe like FindAndReplace working in this case but not much useful in our case.

From the above I can't be certain it's a 100% match, but are you using the build-helper-maven-plugin to add that additional source set? That's not yet supported; tracked here:

https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/issues/755


I crossed checked, I am not using any additional plugin apart from rewrite-maven-plugin in pom.xml of my-recipe project.
Below command we usually use for component test run:-
mvn clean install -Dgroups=ComponentTest.
Does recipe not consider src/component-test folder by default like it run for src/test and src/main? If not then can we have some way to add in pom.xml or in command to make it work?

'
org.openrewrite.maven
rewrite-maven-plugin
latest-version


src/main/java//*.java
src/test/java//.java
src/component-test/java/**/.java


'
I also tried but no luck :(

How are you then ensuring that component test folder is recognized by Maven?

The maven-surefire-plugin is configured in my project to recognize and run tests based on the specified group, ensuring that the tests in the component-test folder are executed. Below is the command we explicitly run for component test:-
mvn clean install -Dgroups=ComponentTest

But if we run through recipe command which mentioned in first post then it doesn`t considered component-test package.
we have also build-helper-maven-plugin mentioned in our target project. Please advice how we can include compoent-test folder while running recipe command.

The build-helper-maven-plugin is not supported yet; details are in the issue linked above.
